# Sort by parameter

Tags: javascript, sorting

This should be a super simple thing, but I am having an issue working this out.  I am trying to implement a sort to move all of one type of objects to the top of a list.  For example, a list of tasks, I would like to sort it so all the tasks of a particular owner appear at the top of the list.  This is what I have now:

```
    this.sortByOwner = function(owner) {
        return tasks.sort(function(a, b) {

            var nameA = a.ownerUser.displayName.toLowerCase();     
            var nameB = b.ownerUser.displayName.toLowerCase();

            var displayName = owner.displayName.toLowerCase();

             if (nameA == displayName) //sort string descending
                 return -1; 
             else if (nameA == "")
                 return 1;
             return 0; //default return value (no sorting)
        });
    };
```

but this doesn't work quite right.  They do appear to be grouping the tasks, but unfortunately, the users tasks are not appearing at the top.  What I would expect to see is the tasks that are owned by the specific person would appear at the top.  What am I doing wrong here?

Including a basic JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/zJwUn/5/

Comment: could you provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: I see Jim twice at the top. Is that not expected?

Comment: Wait, really?  Because I'm not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't handle the case where `nameB` is the `displayName`. This works for me:

```
function sortByOwner(owner) {
    return tasks.sort(function(a, b){
        var nameA=a.displayName.toLowerCase(), nameB=b.displayName.toLowerCase();
        var displayName = owner.displayName.toLowerCase();
        if (nameA == displayName) //sort string descending
            return -1;
        if (nameA == "")
            return 1;
        if (nameB == displayName) //sort string descending
            return 1;
        if (nameB == "")
            return -1;
        return 0; //default return value (no sorting)
    })
}
```

Comment: You're right.  That did the trick.  I forgot, it's a sort function that needs to return something in both cases.  Thanks for this.

Comment: yep it's a compare function, not a key function. no probs!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing at least one check, the case where nameB is the owner.

here's a fixed version from your fiddle

```
function sortByOwner(owner) {
    return tasks.sort(function (a, b) {
        var nameA = a.displayName.toLowerCase(),
            nameB = b.displayName.toLowerCase();
        var displayName = owner.displayName.toLowerCase();

        if (nameA === nameB) return 0;

        if (nameA == displayName) //sort string descending
            return -1;
        if (nameB == displayName) 
            return 1;

        // at this point neither A or B are the owner
        if (nameA == "") return 1;
        if (nameB == "") return -1;

        return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
    })
}
```

Comment: Also +1 for a second correct answer.  Just a split second too late.